# How to change background-repeat and background-size by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I currently have this and it's working for me:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function () {
                var body = $('body');
                var backgrounds = [
                  'url(http://localhost:12448/css/images/back1.jpg) no-repeat',
                  'url(http://localhost:12448/css/images/back2.jpg) no-repeat'];
                var current = 0;

                function nextBackground() {
                    body.css(
                        'background',
                    backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

                    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
                }
                setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
                body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);               
            });
</script>
```

I need to implement also this part of css code in to my javascript, so i can get dynamically changing background and the same css settings as it changes:

```
body
    {
        background-image:           url('images/overlay.png'),      url('images/bg.jpg');
        background-repeat:          repeat,                         no-repeat;
        background-size:            auto,                           100% 100%;
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `.css(attr, val)` is a jQuery method. Are you allowing jquery?

Comment: @Math Nerd Productions yes sure i'm using the library so I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

The main problem here is that you are setting the `background` attribute, which overwrites all of the `-size`, `-repeat`, and `-image` attributes. Instead, change the `background-image` attribute only.

This will require changes to your urls, as you have appended `no-repeat` to the ends of them.

---

#### Some syntactical good practices:

1. Don't define `function`s inside a jQuery ready block.
2. Put your pertinent variables outside the jQuery block so that they are global and can be used in the function.

---

```js
var body = $('body');
var backgrounds = [
    'url(http://fineprintnyc.com/images/blog/history-of-logos/google/google-logo.png)',
    'url(http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Google_logo-8.jpg)'
  ];
var current = 0;

$(function() {

  setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
  body.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});

function nextBackground() {
  body.css(
    'background-image',
    backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

  setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
}
```

```css
html{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url('images/overlay.png'), url('images/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: maybe I didn't ask the right question i need to apply this css to dynamically change background picture (change background picture with): background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100% 100%;

Comment: Well if all you want to change is the image, then use `.css('background-image', ...)` instead of `.css('background', ...)`. See my edit.

Comment: my problem is when image changes i dont have background-size: 100% 100%;

Comment: @codemonkey If you check my edit, you can see I removed the `no-repeat` from the end of your images, and I changed all of the instances of `.css('background'` to `.css('background-image'` You'll see it working if you run the snippet.